# How do I get the GPIO expansion pins to work with input devices (e.g., Distance Sensor)?

Tags: google-aiy

I'm trying to use an HC-SR04 distance sensor with the AIY voice kit. I used the setup in the image link below, except using bonnet PIN_A and PIN_B instead of RPi GPIO23 and 24, and I used a 1000 Ohm and 2000 Ohm resistor for the voltage divider (rather than a 330 and a 470).

[gpiozero docs distance sensor basic recipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqa0o.png)

Here is my script:

```
from gpiozero import DistanceSensor
from time import sleep
from aiy.pins import PIN_A
from aiy.pins import PIN_B

sensor = DistanceSensor(echo=PIN_A, trigger=PIN_B)

while True:
    print('Distance to nearest object is ', sensor.distance, 'm')
    sleep(1)
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "sensor_demo.py", line 6, in
> sensor = DistanceSensor(echo=PIN_A, trigger=PIN_B) File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 124, in
> call self = super(GPIOMeta, cls).call(*args, **kwargs) File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/input_devices.py", line 856,
> in init partial=partial, ignore=frozenset({None}),
> pin_factory=pin_factory File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/input_devices.py", line 277,
> in init pin_factory=pin_factory) File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 197, in init
> super(EventsMixin, self).init(*args, **kwargs) File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/input_devices.py", line 103,
> in init self.pin.pull = pull File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/init.py", line 337, in
> lambda self, value: self._set_pull(value), File
> "/home/pi/AIY-projects-python/src/aiy/pins.py", line 605, in _set_pull
> 'Only pull up is supported right now (%s)' % pull)
> gpiozero.exc.PinFixedPull: Only pull up is supported right now (down)

When I run it on a RPi 1 B+ directly (with RPi GPIO pins), it works fine, so I think it has to do with the GPIO expansion pins on the bonnet, especially when they are used for input, like [here](https://github.com/google/aiyprojects-raspbian/issues/331#issuecomment-405769640), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59973849/is-there-any-example-of-how-to-use-the-digital-input-or-analog-input-of-gpio-on), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61507324/gpio-zero-button-press-error-with-aiy-pins-py).

Is there any way to make this work with the GPIO expansion pins, or do I have to take the RPi 0 out of the box and use its pins?

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed the error and went through the gpiozero documentation. So according to the PinFixedPull error

> Error raised when attempting to set the pull of a pin with fixed pull-up

So this is most likely a physical hardware issue with the pins because it says right on your error that only pull up is supported.

Comment: Thanks. I found a workaround. Eventually, I just separated the bonnet from the Pi 0W and then reconnected them with jumper wires according to [this pinout](https://github.com/google/aiyprojects-raspbian/issues/331#issuecomment-404990798). That gave me access to the Pi's other pins for input devices.